# NSMutableArrayに追加した要素であるUIViewをAddSubViewしてもViewが生成されない。

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

#### 前提・実現したいこと

TinderのようなViewをスライドさせて次のViewを表示させるアプリを開発しております。
すべてのViewをスライドさせ終わったら、もう一度すべてのViewが生成されるように実装したいのです。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

NSMutableArrayに追加した要素であるUIViewをAddSubViewしても追加できません。

@IBAction func tappedReset()を呼び出してもViewが表示されません。

setViewImage()を呼び出してからなら生成されます。
以下、コードになります。アドバイスいただければありがたいです。

#### ソースコード

```
//SubmitBtnをタップするとViewが生成
@IBAction func tappedSubmitBtn() {
    setViewImage()
    if numberOfTotalView > 0 {
        self.view.insertSubview(cardViewArray.objectAtIndex(numberOfTotalView) as! UIView,
                                aboveSubview: cardViewArray.objectAtIndex(numberOfTotalView - 1) as! UIView)
    }else{
        self.view.addSubview(cardViewArray.objectAtIndex(numberOfTotalView) as! UIView)
    }

}

//setViewImageメソッドの呼び出し
func setViewImage(index: Int) {
    let options = MDCSwipeToChooseViewOptions()
    options.delegate = self
    options.likedText = "Keep"
    options.likedColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    options.nopeText = "Delete"
    options.onPan = { state -> Void in
        if state.thresholdRatio == 1 && state.direction == MDCSwipeDirection.Left {
        }
    }
    let card = MDCSwipeToChooseView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 70, width: 320, height: 320), options: options)
    card.imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageView1 )

    cardViewArray.addObject(card)
    return
}

//上記でcardViewArray.addObjectで追加後に、以下のメソッドを呼び出してもViewが表示されない。
@IBAction func tappedReset() {
    if numberOfTotalView > 0 {
        print("insetSubView")
        self.view.insertSubview(cardViewArray.objectAtIndex(numberOfTotalView) as! UIView,
                                aboveSubview: cardViewArray.objectAtIndex(numberOfTotalView - 1) as! UIView)
    } else {
        print("addSubview")

        self.view.addSubview(cardViewArray.objectAtIndex(0) as! UIView)
    }
}
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/21706